# It was delayed to subscribe a image topic by frame rate of Images

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, topic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, guys.
I have used ROS Kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.

I make a two node. The one is publisher node to publish image topic.
Another is subscriber node to subscribe publisher's topic.

The transmission period of the publisher node is 30 fps approximately.
As you can see in the code below,  When I remove the remark of line include the `cv::wait(30)` function, Subscriber does not work at regular intervals.

I can not find a clue.
Can you tell me what keywords I can find information about?

```
...(On Subscriber Node)...
while(ros::ok()) {
    ros::spinOnce();
    image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/video/image/ch0", 1, &imageCb);  // 30 fps by publisher!
    // chKey = cv::waitKey(30);
}
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289485/it-was-delayed-to-subscribe-a-image-topic-by-frame-rate-of-images./) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You only need to subscribe to the image topic once, do not put this line within the main while loop of your code.

What you're telling ROS to do is re-subscribe to the same topic every iteration of the loop, this is not going to work well at all.

Move the subscribe line outside of the loop, then it should start working as you expect.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-05-03**:
Thanks to that I understood well.